# Listing Data from Api calls in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to practice dependency injections and API calls in Compose but there is a problem , whenever I try to display the Card Composable it doesn't display the Card. I have checked the API call and it seems to be working properly in LogCat. Here is my code:

**YuGiOhApp.kt**

```
    @SuppressLint("StateFlowValueCalledInComposition")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun YuGiOhApp(cardViewModel: CardViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = { AppTopAppBar(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior) }
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it)
        ) {
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = "cards"){

            }

            cardViewModel.cards.value?.let { it ->
                HomeScreen(
                    it.data
                )
            }
        }
    }
}



@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppTopAppBar(scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
        title = {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.yugi),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall,
            )
        },
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

**HomeScreen.kt**

```
@SuppressLint("StateFlowValueCalledInComposition")
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(cards: List<Data>,modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

  LazyColumn(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
      Log.i("IN the column","yayaya")
          items(cards){card ->
              Card(modifier = modifier, card = card)
              Log.i("IN THE ITEMS","tatata")
      }

  }


}

@Composable
fun Card(modifier: Modifier, card: Data) {
    Column() {
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(context = LocalContext.current)
                .data(card.cardİmages.get(0)).build(),
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.card),
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Text(text = card.name, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    }
}
```

**ViewModelClass**

```
@HiltViewModel
class CardViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: CardRepo) : ViewModel() {
    var cards = MutableStateFlow<CardResponse?>(null)
    private set


    init {
        getCards()
    }

    private fun getCards() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getNetwork().enqueue(object : Callback<CardResponse>{
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<CardResponse>,
                    response: Response<CardResponse>
                ) {
                    cards.value = response.body()
                    Log.i("message: ", response.body().toString() )
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<CardResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    cards.value = null
                }

            })
        }
    }

    fun observeUIState() = cards.asStateFlow()

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            YuGiOhCardsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<CardViewModel>()
                    YuGiOhApp(cardViewModel = viewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? What exactly happens after the API call response comes in?

Comment: It seems to work fine but it doesn't reach into LazyColumn in HomeScreen.kt

Comment: It might be that you are using `cardViewModel.cards.value` instead of using `collectAsState()`.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the problem, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`YuGiOhApp` Composable function change to:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun YuGiOhApp(cardViewModel: CardViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    // Better to use cardViewModel.observeUIState().collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    // it's in library androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose
    val uiState by cardViewModel.observeUIState().collectAsState()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = { AppTopAppBar(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior) }
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it)
        ) {
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = "cards"){

            }

            HomeScreen(
                uiState.data
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The key result is that there is no recomposition when your `CardViewModel` data changed, so the UI won't update. You must use `State` to tell Compose to update, the `collectAsState` function is used to convert `StateFlow` to `State`.

See document https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state about Compose State and https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/consuming-flows-safely-in-jetpack-compose-cde014d0d5a3 about `collectAsStateWithLifecycle`